# Take multiple patterns from cli. argparse Python3

Tags: python, grep, command-line-arguments, argparse, sys

I have a python version of grep, that I am building for an assignment.  I want my python module to take multiple patterns from the command line, just like grep.  However no matter what I do, I keep getting conflicts with my 'debug' argument.

This is what it currently looks like from command line (with -h):

```
pgreper.py [-h] [--debug] pattern
```

At the moment I can only search with one pattern:

```
cat input.txt | ./pgreper.py "were"
```

I would like to be able to search the input.txt file like so, with multiple patterns:

```
cat input.txt | ./pgreper.py "were" "you"
```

However when I try and do this, I get the following error:

```
pgreper.py: error: unrecognized argument: you
```

I know that it is related to the fact I generate a pattern to search by reading sys.argv[1].  How would I go about editing my script, to allow it to take multiple patterns from sys.argv, without affecting the optional arguments I have implemented?

Many thanks :)

ps Please ignore my comments, thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import re
import time
import datetime
import inspect
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python Grep.')
parser.add_argument('--debug', default='debug', action='store_true', help='Print debug messages')
parser.add_argument('pattern', type=str, help='Pattern for pgrepping')
args = parser.parse_args()


class CodeTrace(object):
    def __init__(self, line, pattern):
        self.line = line
        self.pattern = pattern

    # @staticmethod
    def trace(self, line, pattern):
        # Creating Timestamp
        ts = time.time()
        # Formatting Timestamp
        ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f]')
        stack = inspect.stack()
        # Retrieve calling class information
        the_class = stack[1][0].f_locals["self"].__class__
        # Retrieve calling method information
        the_method = stack[1][0].f_code.co_name
        the_variables = stack[1][0].f_code.co_varnames
        # Formats the contents of the debug trace into a readable format,
        # Any parameters passed to the method and the return value, are included in    the debug trace
        debug_trace = ("{} {}.{}.{} {} {} ".format(ts, str(the_class), the_method, the_variables, pattern, line))
        # Send out the debug trace as a standard error output
        sys.stderr.write(debug_trace + "\n")


class Grepper(object):
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self.pattern = pattern

    # @CodeTrace.trace()
    def matchline(self, pattern):
        regex = re.compile(self.pattern)
        for line in sys.stdin:
            if regex.search(line):
                sys.stdout.write(line)
                if args.debug != 'debug':
                    (CodeTrace(line, pattern).trace(line, pattern))


def main():
    pattern = str(sys.argv[1])
    print(sys.argv)
    Grepper(pattern).matchline(pattern)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why is your `main()` function ignoring the parsed arguments stored in `args`?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean :(

Comment: You asked `argparse` to parse `sys.argv` for you, then ignore the result and use `sys.argv[1]` directly.

Comment: Good point, would replacing the line in question with this pattern = str(args['pattern']), sort the problem?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to use `str()` there; you already have strings. Personally, I'd move all the `argparse` code into the `main()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell `argparse` to expect 1 or more arguments, using the [`nargs` keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs):

```
parser.add_argument('patterns', type=str, nargs='+', help='Pattern(s) for pgrepping')
```

Here `+` means *1 or more*. You can then combine these patterns:

```
pattern = '|'.join(['(?:{})'.format(p) for p in args.patterns])
```

and pass that to your grepper. The patterns are combined with `|` after first being placed in a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) to make sure each pattern is treated as distinct.

I'd place all argument parsing in the `main()` function here:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python Grep.')
    parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true', help='Print debug messages')
    parser.add_argument('pattern', type=str, nargs='+', help='Pattern(s) for pgrepping')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    pattern = '|'.join(['(?:{})'.format(p) for p in args.pattern])
    Grepper(pattern, args.debug).matchline()
```

I also removed the default for the `--debug` option; using `store_true` means it'll default to `False`; you can then simply test for `args.debug` being true or not.

You don't need to pass in `pattern` twice to `Grepper()`; you can simply use `self.pattern` in the `matchline` method, throughout. Instead, I'd pass in `args.debug` to `Grepper()` as well (no need for it to be a global).

Quick demo of what the argument parsing look like, including the help message:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python Grep.')
>>> parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true', help='Print debug messages')
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--debug'], dest='debug', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help='Print debug messages', metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('pattern', type=str, nargs='+', help='Pattern(s) for pgrepping')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='pattern', nargs='+', const=None, default=None, type=<type 'str'>, choices=None, help='Pattern(s) for pgrepping', metavar=None)
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [-h] [--debug] pattern [pattern ...]

Python Grep.

positional arguments:
  pattern     Pattern(s) for pgrepping

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --debug     Print debug messages
>>> parser.parse_args(['where'])
Namespace(debug=False, pattern=['where'])
>>> parser.parse_args(['were'])
Namespace(debug=False, pattern=['were'])
>>> parser.parse_args(['were', 'you'])
Namespace(debug=False, pattern=['were', 'you'])
>>> parser.parse_args(['--debug', 'were', 'you'])
Namespace(debug=True, pattern=['were', 'you'])
```

The pattern then looks like this:

```
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['were', 'you'])
>>> args.pattern
['were', 'you']
>>> pattern = '|'.join(['(?:{})'.format(p) for p in args.pattern])
>>> pattern
'(?:were)|(?:you)'
```

If instead you wanted *all* patterns to match, you'll need to alter `Grepper()` to take multiple patterns and test all those patterns. Use the [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to make that efficient (only test as many patterns as is required):

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python Grep.')
    parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true', help='Print debug messages')
    parser.add_argument('pattern', type=str, nargs='+', help='Pattern(s) for pgrepping')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    Grepper(args.pattern, args.debug).matchline()
```

and the `Grepper` class becomes:

```
class Grepper(object):
    def __init__(self, patterns, debug=False):
        self.patterns = [re.compile(p) for p in patterns]
        self.debug = debug

    def matchline(self, debug):
        for line in sys.stdin:
            if all(p.search(line) for p in self.patterns):
                sys.stdout.write(line)
                if self.debug:
                    CodeTrace(line, self.patterns).trace(line)
```

with appropriate adjustments for the `CodeTrace` class.

Comment: Just wondering, how would that be implemented on the cli?

e.g. cat input.txt | .pgreper.py "Were|wolf"

Comment: @jeff_h: `./pgrepper.py were wolf`. Also see the `--help` output I included in the demo.

Comment: This is really good, thanks for all your help so far :)  However, it appears to be printing any thing that has ether pattern in it, rather than only printing something with both patterns in it.  Which is what I am trying to do, sorry if I didn't make that clear :(

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, you have helped me through this :)  I am just making changes to the CodeTrace class now.  Not 100% sure what they are haha, but I should be fine.

Comment: I will accept your answer, once I make the correct changes to my CodeTrace class :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you, this code is a little above me, I am getting a unbalanced parenthesis error, on line: self.patterns = [re.complie(p) for p in patterns], could you help me out?  :)

Comment: What patterns are you passing in? You have a pattern with `(` or `)` in it?

Comment: No my patterns are just two words:  cat input.txt | ./pgreper.py "Were" "Mill"

Comment: I'll have to follow up tomorrow, but what exactly is contained in `patterns` when you get that exception? Add a `print` call.

Comment: @jeff_h: I notice this morning that my `main()` was passing in a global `pattern` rather than `args.pattern`; perhaps you still had such a global and it contained parentheses?

Comment: That was it!  It now accepts multiple patterns :D  Just sorting out debug option and that should be me done, I hope :)  Got debugs sorted now as well, happy to accept all your hard work as the answer :D

Comment: New python puzzle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945035/token-capture-sequences-python-not-working-correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your argparse argument configuration were not correct. This is really now how you configure the argument. Check the Python documentation for argparse as there is a very good example in there.

the format should always be `yourscript.py -aARGUMENTVAL -bARGUMENTVAL ...etc.` the -a and -b styles are important.

Your code is edited to have a better application of argparse module below. See if this works better (without action argument for debug):

```
import sys
import re
import time
import datetime
import inspect
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python Grep.')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--pattern', type=str, help='Pattern for pgrepping')
parser.add_argument('-d','--debug', type=str, default="false", help='Print debug messages')
args = vars(parser.parse_args());


class CodeTrace(object):
    def __init__(self, line, pattern):
        self.line = line
        self.pattern = pattern

    # @staticmethod
    def trace(self, line, pattern):
        # Creating Timestamp
        ts = time.time()
        # Formatting Timestamp
        ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f]')
        stack = inspect.stack()
        # Retrieve calling class information
        the_class = stack[1][0].f_locals["self"].__class__
        # Retrieve calling method information
        the_method = stack[1][0].f_code.co_name
        the_variables = stack[1][0].f_code.co_varnames
        # Formats the contents of the debug trace into a readable format,
        # Any parameters passed to the method and the return value, are included in    the debug trace
        debug_trace = ("{} {}.{}.{} {} {} ".format(ts, str(the_class), the_method, the_variables, pattern, line))
        # Send out the debug trace as a standard error output
        sys.stderr.write(debug_trace + "\n")


class Grepper(object):
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self.pattern = pattern

    # @CodeTrace.trace()
    def matchline(self, pattern):
        regex = re.compile(self.pattern)
        for line in sys.stdin:
            if regex.search(line):
                sys.stdout.write(line)
                if args.debug != 'debug':
                    (CodeTrace(line, pattern).trace(line, pattern))


def main():
    pattern = str(args['pattern'])
    print(sys.argv)
    Grepper(pattern).matchline(pattern)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can supply comma delimited string to separate patters `-p"were,you". Use python's powerful string functions for that

```
pattern = ((args['pattern']).replace(" ", "")).split(",");
```

the above will give you a list of patterns to look for?

Comment: That is an improvement, I ran it as the following:

cat input.txt | ./pgreper.py --p "the" --p "vir"

However the script now only prints lines that include the second pattern, ignoring the first pattern.

Comment: why can't you just supply a comma-delimited string? and then strip it out?