# token capture sequences python not working correctly

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, token

I am testing out my python grepper script.  It takes multiple search patterns, and works well with regular expressions and plain text.

For this test, my input.txt has the following two lines:

```
foo blah is a bar
foo blah is bar
```

If I run:

```
cat input.txt | ./pgreper.py "foo %{0} is a %{1}"
```

I should get: foo blah is a bar, as output, however I get nothing.

Any help in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

ps please ignore my comments.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import re
import time
import datetime
import inspect
import argparse

# The following section allows arguments to be passed to the module, eg input | ./pgreper.py pattern pattern --debug
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python Grep.')
# Enable debugging, by adding --debug at the end of command
parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true', help='Print debug messages')
# nargs='+', enables multiple patterns to be entered at the commandline eg input | ./pgreper.py pattern pattern
parser.add_argument('pattern', type=str, nargs='+', help='Pattern(s) for pgrepping')
args = parser.parse_args()


# This is the class that allows for debugging a line in sys.stdin, if it matches all patterns.
class CodeTrace(object):
    def __init__(self, line, pattern):
        self.line = line
        self.pattern = pattern

    # @staticmethod
    # This is the degugging method
    def trace(self, line, pattern):
        # Capture the current time, and format the timestamp, into a readable format
        ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f]')
        # Inspect allows us to blah, inspecting the stack allows us to retrieve information
        stack = inspect.stack()
        # Retrieve calling class information
        the_class = stack[1][0].f_locals["self"].__class__
        # Retrieves the calling method information
        the_method = stack[1][0].f_code.co_name
        # Retrieves the calling method's variables
        the_variables = stack[1][0].f_code.co_varnames
        # Formats the contents of the debug trace into a readable format,
        # Any parameters passed to the method and the return value, are included in the debug trace
        debug_trace = ("{} {}.{}.{} {} {} ".format(ts, str(the_class), the_method,the_variables, pattern, line))
        # Send out the debug trace as a standard error output
        sys.stderr.write(debug_trace + "\n")


# This is the class that does the pattern matching
class Grepper(object):
    def __init__(self, patterns, debug=False):
        # Every pattern that this module takes is compiled here, so that it may be searched for in sys.stdin
        self.patterns = [re.compile(p) for p in patterns]
        self.debug = debug

    # This method compares the input, to the patterns compiled in Grepper
    def matchline(self, debug):
        for line in sys.stdin:
            # This line compares all the patterns to the input, only if the input matches ALL patterns does it pass
            if all(p.search(line) for p in self.patterns):
                sys.stdout.write(line)
                # this if statement runs the CodeTrace.trace function, if the user adds the --debug option in the cli
                if self.debug:
                    CodeTrace(line, self.patterns).trace(line, args.pattern)


# This main function calls the grepper class and the matchline method, for the purpose of pattern matching
def main():
    print(args.pattern)
    Grepper(args.pattern, args.debug).matchline(args.debug)

# This allows the module to be used as a standalone module, or a reusable module in a different program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Well, the input file doesn't contain the text `foo %{0} is a %{1}`. Did you mean to replace the `%{...}` placeholders with some kind of regular expression like `\w+`?

Comment: Your right, I just checked it using an online reg checker... I am just going by what is on my assignment worksheet... what would match foo %{0} is a %{1}?

Comment: try `cat input.txt | ./pygrepper.py foo [a-z] is a [a-z]` or `cat input.txt | ./pygrepper.py foo \\w+ is a \\w+
`

Comment: `foo %{0} is a %{1}` interpreted as a regular expression would match `foo  is a %`.

Comment: "foo is a %", returns nothing :(

Comment: @jeff_h: There are two spaces between `foo` and `is`.

Comment: @rawing cat input.txt | ./pgreper.py "foo %{0}is a%{1}" returns nothing

Comment: @jeff_h: That's because `foo %{0} is a %{1}` is interpreted as a regular expression (which matches `foo is a %`), but there is no `foo is a %` in your input file.

Comment: Straight from my worksheet:

For example of a pattern with only simple token escape sequences follows:
"foo %{0} is a %{1}"
which would match the following text strings:
"foo blah is a bar"
"foo blah is a very big boat"
but would not match the following text strings:
"foo blah is bar"
"foo blah"
"foo blah is"

Now I am confused haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently interpreting the command line arguments as regex patterns, without replacing the placeholders `%{0}` and `%{1}`. You'll probably want to replace the placeholders with `.*` or something similar, like so:

```
class Grepper(object):
    def __init__(self, patterns, debug=False):
        patterns= [re.sub(r'%\{\d\}', '.*', p) for p in patterns]
        self.patterns = [re.compile(p) for p in patterns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, thats it sorted :)

Comment: If I wanted "bar %{0G} foo %{1}" to match; bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo.  What would I need to substitute?

Comment: @jeff_h: Try `%\{\w*\}` instead of `%\{\d\}`.

Comment: Yep that did it, how are you working this out?  Is there a website I can use?  So I don't have to keep bothering you? hehe

Comment: That's basic regular expressions. You can read the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html), or if you just need a reference, I'd recommend [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regular+expressions&ia=answer). You can experiment with regex online at [regex101](https://regex101.com/#python).